# Find dates in current month corresponding to a given weekday

Tags: swift

I am currently making a scheduling feature for my application. I have a view where a user is able to select what days of the week they will be available for. Now, I am looking for a way to generate an array of dates for the given weekdays for the upcoming month.

In other words, if the user selects that they will be available on Monday, the function needs to return all dates that satisfy the given predicament for the month ahead (4 date objects).

Here's what I have tried but it doesn't seem to work:

```
var masterSchedule = [WorkDay(weekDay: 1, startTime: 8, endTime: 16, busyHours: []), WorkDay(weekDay: 4, startTime: 8, endTime: 16, busyHours: [])]

func getDates() {
    for workDay in masterSchedule {
        var components = DateComponents()
        
        components.weekday = workDay.weekDay
        components.year = 2021
        components.month = 8
        
        
        let date = Calendar.current.date(from: components) ?? Date()
        availableDays.append(date)
        
    }
}
```

For some reason, the output returns 2 same dates of `2021-07-31 23:00:00 +0000`.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You can't ask for "the best way to do that", that is not an appropriate question for stackoverflow. Do some research, start working on a solution and then come back with your question and the code you have if you run into a problem.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thank you for your suggestion, I have updated my question with the code I have tried to resolve my problem with.

Comment: Can you please add the `masterSchedule` array to the code?

Comment: @Tadreik added the array!

Comment: Take the date you currently create and then in a loop add /increase by  a week to get the following 3 days of that weekday, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293453-date

Comment: Just add 7 days to the selected weekday, until it gets out of the current month.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that prints all the Mondays in October

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport


let calendar = Calendar.current
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .short

let firstOfOctober = formatter.date(from: "10/1/2021")!

if let interval = calendar.dateInterval(of: .month, for: firstOfOctober) {

    let mondays = DateComponents(weekday: 2)
    calendar.enumerateDates(startingAfter: firstOfOctober,
                            matching: mondays, matchingPolicy: .previousTimePreservingSmallerComponents) {
        date, exactMatch, stopLooking in
        if let date = date {
            if date < interval.end {
                print(formatter.string(from: date))
            } else {
                stopLooking = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```